# ReplaySubject with distinct elements

Tags: rx-java2, behaviorsubject

I want to implement an EventBus with RxJava and I need sticky events. I know I can use a BehaviorSubject but it caches only the last emitted item while I want to cache all events that are distinct by their type(class name). There is another option - ReplaySubject however it has an overhead - it holds all the emitted elements.
Is there a way to create some kind of a ReplaySubject which would hold only unique by type elements?

Comment: You can filter the items before you emit them in the `Subject`. So they will be already unique by type when they are received in the `Subject`.

Comment: @masp it's an event bus. It's like an infinity stream. I don't know how much items I will emit, so I can't collect them and filter before sending them to a subject

Comment: You want to cache the latest element by type? Then have multiple BehaviorSubjects or ReplaySubjects, one for each type which also gives you type safety.

Comment: @akarnokd No, I want to have all elements sent to my subject. But they should be unique by type. So if I call something like subject.onNext(a), subject.onNext(b), subject.onNext(a), I would like to have [b, latest a] cached. I don't need type safety since it's an event bus

Comment: That case requires a custom Subject with non-trivial internals due to increased concurrency effects. I'd rather avoid event busses entirely as they are a step backwards from ReactiveX anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there are any clean solutions. However, you might be able to make this work.

1. Create a `BehaviorSubject<>` for each event type. Use a `ConcurrentMap` to dispatch each incoming event to the correct `Subject`.
2. Maintain a list of those subjects in the order of arrival of events.
3. When a new subscription is received, an observable will be created that is the merge of all the subjects, with the first list of subjects that have already received events, followed by those that have not in any order.

This is some code that might clarify the above. Untested.

```
// The subscription operation will perform a merge of the two lists
Map<EventType, BehaviorSubject<Event>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
List<BehaviorSubject<Event>> listOfUnseenEvents = new ArrayList<>();
List<BehaviorSubject<Event>> listOfSeenEvents = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
listOfUnseenEvents = map.values().asList();

public Observable<Event> busSub() {
  List<BehaviorSubject<Event>> allEvents = new ArrayList<>();
  synchronized ( map ) {
    allEvents.addAll( listOfSeenEvents );
    allEvents.addAll( listOfUnseenEvents );
  }
  return Observable.merge( allEvents );
}

// receive an event and dispatch it
eventSource
  .subscribe( event -> processEvent( event ) );

public void processEvent( Event event ) {
    BehaviorSubject<Event> eSubject = map.get( event.getEventType() );
    synchronized ( map ) {
      if ( containsEventType( listOfSeenEvents, event.getEventType() ) ) {
        removeEventType( listOfSeenEvents, event.getEventType() );
      } else {
        removeEventType( listOfUnseenEvents, event.getEventType() );
      }
      listOfSeenEvents.add( eSubject );
    }
    eSubject.onNext( event );
}
```

Please note that this code takes advantage of the fact that `merge()` will subscribe to each of the given observables in order. There is no guarantee of such in the RxJava documentation.

If all the event types are not known in advance, then this won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I don't need to distinguish between seen and unseen events, so it could be simplified, Also why will this not work if all event types are undetermined? I can group events by their type and it seems to be enough to post only the latest event of the certain type

Comment: You need "unseen" event subjects so that subscribers will eventually see events for those types.  Otherwise, you would need have an "unclassified" subject for each subscriber, and a list of event types that fall into unclassified.

Answer (score 1):

I do no succeed to solve this issue with only one stream.
So I have one stream by event type, and only expose a merged stream.

```
open class Event(val name: String)
class Event1(name: String) : Event(name)
class Event2(name: String) : Event(name)

val event1Subject = BehaviorSubject.create<Event1>()
val event2Subject = BehaviorSubject.create<Event2>()

event1Subject.onNext(Event1("event1 a"))
event1Subject.onNext(Event1("event1 b"))
event2Subject.onNext(Event2("event2 a"))
event2Subject.onNext(Event2("event2 b"))

Observable.merge(event1Subject, event2Subject)
        .subscribe { println(it.name) }
```

Console ouput :

```
event1 b
event2 b
```